# Angular ng-auth-token does not close the window on redirect safari

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, safari

I am using ng auth token and rails devise token, when i am login in ios safari the window is stuck on the "redirecting" window and does not close the window.

This is the code that run to close the window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var usingExternalWindow = function() {
        var nav     = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
            ieLTE10 = (nav && nav.indexOf('msie') != -1),
            ie11    = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
        return !(ieLTE10 || ie11);
      }

      if (usingExternalWindow()) {
        window.addEventListener("message", function(ev) {
          if (ev.data === "requestCredentials") {
            ev.source.postMessage({
              <%= yield %>
            }, '*');
            window.close();
          }
        });
      } else {
        window.location.href = "<%= @auth_origin_url %>";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
      Redirecting...
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

In all other browsers this is working fine and here its seems like the postMessage does not send to the new tab.

Comment: which safari version ?

Comment: what i experienced is that when the origin tab is out of scope the javascript stops executing, so the origin tab doesn't send the postMessage the api page is waiting for so it doesn't send back the postMessage response and don't close, try to go to the origin tab and test by yourself, a solution may be is to use same window as they merged it in the last release https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth#oauth2-authentication-flow